# Why this submit form "check list" data doesn't send to email with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

I am trying to create a check list that allows users to check off each item they want and then send an email to their chosen email. I am using JQueryMobile and I don't know if it's causing any problems, but the page just keeps on loading continuously when I press submit.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form name="emailform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form-to-email.php" method="post">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for='name'>Festival name: </label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name">
   <h3>
   Essentials
   </h3>


   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
    <legend>
    </legend>
    <input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox1">
    Tickets
    </label>
    <input name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox2">
    Parking pass
    </label>
    <input name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox3">
    Directions
    </label>
    <input name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox4">
    Cash &amp; Cards
    </label>
    <input name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox5">
     Keys
    </label>
    </fieldset>

     <label for='email'>Send to Email:</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="email">

     <input name="share" type="submit" value="Share">

     </form>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
    <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!$_POST['name'] | !$_POST['email']) 
    {
    echo"<div class='error'>Error<br />You did not fill in a required field, please       review your form and correct the missing information.</div>";
    }
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $checkbox1 = $_POST['checkbox1'];

    $email_from = "Application";
    $email_subject = $name;
    $email_body = "You have received a new checklist via App.\n".
    "Here is the checklist so far:\n $checkbox1".

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    mail($email, $email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header('Location: index.html');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send email from localhost, then you will definitely face this error as there are no mail settings by default. However you can install a test mail server on your computer to test emails from localhost.

If you are sending the email from live server then you need to follow this tutorial to overcome any issues that might be in your code: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: Hello, yeah I am testing it on a live server. w3schools is great but I just can't find a reason why mine isn't send.

cheers anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you should communicate through AJAX with jQuery, In that case you should NOT send headers. Also you should note that checkbox values are TRUE/FALSE, so

"You have received a new checklist via App.".
   "Here is the checklist so far: ".

Comment: With checkboxes being true or false, does that mean that only the boxes marked (true) would show up in the email?